# Dual boot Windows 7 or 10 alongside Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I already have Ubuntu installed, newest version I believe, and would like to dual boot Windows 7 or 10 (which ever is easier). Most the guides I find are for people who have Windows and want to dual boot Ubuntu, but is there a way to do it the other way around? All I can find is for the Windows to Ubuntu way and not Ubuntu to Windows.

I want to keep Ubuntu as my main OS and Windows as my secondary for video games.

I've been reading a bit though that this is kind of hard too do, as Windows doesn't like being a secondary OS.

Thanks.

Comment: do u have UEFI enabled pc, are u using gpt disk layout?

Answer (score 1):

**This is defiantly possible!**

You have to have a spare partition or drive for Windows to install on in the first place.

The tricky part is that Windows as you stated does not "like" to be installed alongside Ubuntu. The problem is that when installing Windows aside a Ubuntu system it will override Grub with the Windows boot loader, which makes Ubuntu inaccessible.

See this question for more infos on how to install Windows **after** Ubuntu: [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)